# Streaming live audio from one IOS Device to another

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, audio-streaming

I'm wondering if anyone has any advice on how to stream audio from one IOS device to another.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You search an app  or you want to know how to code something like that?